# Simple example of a custom workflow with email and single approval

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

So I have been tasked with creating a SharePoint calendar that allows approved people to enter an event in a calendar. They will then receive a confirmation email that they workflow has been started. An authorized approver will then either accept or reject the event. Upon hitting OK the workflow should be finalized and the original submitter should receive an email reflecting the status of the event.

Sounds like an out of the box approval workflow but there are some details that have me stumped. When I create an approval workflow in SharePoint designer I can customize the original email that is sent to the submitter easily enough. I am getting stuck at the process of simplifying the approval/rejection part of the workflow. Typically you have to finalize the workflow task but I want the accept/reject stage to accomplish this. What am I changing to do this.

Basically, I want the simplest event approval workflow possible that will send an email upon creation to the submitter, allow the accept/reject stage to finalize the workflow and send an email to the submitter with the results.

A link to an example would be fantastic if there is such a thing. I have been searching this off and on for quite some time.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple video to create a custom workflow with SharePoint designer.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/video-create-an-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-VA101897477.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I have seen that horrible video before and it doesn't apply to my question. Custom workflows are not the problem it's a step in the custom workflow that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

what i understand, you want the mark the workflow complete even if it item rejected, correct?
Open the workflow in SharePoint designer.
Add an action on top of the Start Approval Process: Set workflow variable. Set the variable: CancelonRejection to Yes.
In this way, the approval process will end on for rejection. Publish the workflow to have a test.

or check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451095/how-do-i-create-an-approval-workflow-that-updates-the-list-item-that-started-the

Comment: I have tried your suggestion without success. Basically I want the workflow task to end upon the first(only) accept/reject. I can see where in the process the CancelonRejection variable is checked and while it seemed like a great idea the task never completes and fires off the last email (<< important).